# TextLabelWidget AndroidPlot get position

Tags: android, androidplot

I am setting an `onTouchListener` to the `XYPlot` like in the `AndroidPlot` example application.

I want to know when the user touches the x domain title, y domain title, or the general title. There is no `getRect()` function for the class `TextLabelWidget`, but there is one for the `XYGraphWidget`. Should I edit the android plot project and push it? Or did I misread the code and is there already this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I did overlook the functionality. I was looking for something like this:

```
plot.getTitleWidget().getGridRect().contains(point.x, point.y))
```

But it turns out that there is a function for the widget itself and I would not have to get the `RectF` android object. The below works fine:

```
plot.getTitleWidget().contains(PointFObj)
```